# Admin name appears twice if it asks for admin password. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, security, administrator, adduser, execute-command

I was trying to apply some given items at [this page](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics) to secure my Ubuntu 12,04. After applying item number 4; my user name which is the only admin, appears twice if system asks for an admin password as seen below.

[image]

How to revert it back to its original state.

Thank you.

Hejar

Comment: The page you posted is not found.

Comment: The page that you're referring to in your question doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you provide info on what's the Step 4?

Comment: 4.) Protect su by limiting access only to admin group: Open a terminal window and enter:                                      sudo groupadd admin
sudo usermod -a -G admin <YOUR ADMIN USERNAME>
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root admin 4750 /bin/su  P.S.: I corrected the link.

Comment: I don't think protecting su is needed since any new added user isn't an admin by default. You can also go to: System Settings->user accounts, select the account you want and remove it from the admin group if it's added automatically to it.

Comment: It is still me (Hejar) the only admin shown there. But when system asks me to put admin password my name appears twice. Why that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I' going to take a stab at this.

I have to say, that during the installation an admin group was created, and you were added to it.  So by Protect su by limiting access only to admin group, you have added yourself again, and that's why you see yourself listed twice.

Reverse what you did, and see if it removes that extra you.

Comment: How to reverse it. What's the command? Thank you.

Comment: Try `deluser <username> <groupname>`

Comment: Dear Mitch. I tried the deluser <username> <groupname> and it WORKED like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear Mitch I think now I have another problem persisted. Although by using my password I can open Synaptic Package Manager but commands through Terminal doesn’t work as seen in this picture [link](http://imgur.com/R0dixsf).  @Mitch Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/getting-permission-denied-when-running-sudo-bash-925656/), and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1672781).

Comment: @HejarMukriyani Out of curiosity, why un-accept?

Comment: As I told, it removes extra of me but leads to another problem that I can't command in Terminal any-more. Tried to find a solution in the two links that you suggested but couldn't able to success. Finally I decided to re-format my HDD and re-install Ubuntu 12.04. Again thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Fair enough.  You're welcome.  Sorry that it did work for you.